# How to open ipython command history on a text editor?

Tags: ipython

I am using a windows machine and would like to open ipython history commands using the default text editor. Is there a command that allows me to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
%edit 1-4
```

That should open lines 1-4 from the current session in an editor. You can get previous sessions as well - run `%hist?` to see how the syntax works.

You may need to set the `EDITOR` environment variable to a command that launches your favourite editor.

Comment: That exact command got me into an infinite loop of `editor` sessions, every third of which contained three lines of history. I had to kill the session. WTF?

Comment: Weird. If you can replicate it, could you [file a bug](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues?state=open), including details like your OS and your EDITOR setting.

Comment: Replicable on two machines, one running 0.12.1 and another running 0.13.2.

Comment: Heh, I guess I'm the bug - Of course, if you start `%edit 1-4`, then close and save the file which pops up, what's gonna happen? The saved file is going to be executed, as per the docs. And the last line of that file is the Python code equivalent to the `%edit 1-4` magic, so you're effectively re-running the `%edit` command. Workaround: Read the docs and/or clear the file before saving and exiting.

Comment: Ah. Alternative workaround: try it at input prompt *5*. ;-) More seriously, I wonder if there's a sensible way we can protect against that, by disabling `%edit` commands when running code from an `%edit` command.

Comment: Tricky, if you want to avoid aggravating people who legitimately want to do some editing magic. What about making `%edit` *not* execute by default - I first thought it was used simply to save commands as a script for later. Alternatively, shift the semantics slightly so that the `%edit` line is #0 rather than #1. This sort of emulates C/Bash/Python argument #0, which is the command itself.

Comment: %edit isn't line 1, though - it's whichever line you write it on. However you number them, you can easily select a range to edit that includes an `%edit` command. Not executing by default might be a bit safer, but you'd still be able to hit the problem with `%edit -x` (or whatever). However, I doubt many people are legitimately using %edit commands from other files they've edited.